# Show hidden DIV in bootstrap modal with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following form:[image]

Whenever the user clicks on '*Don't have a Paypal account?*', I want to display another form within the modal.

[image]

However, after displaying the hidden DIV and scrolling the modal, the background fade will scroll as well.

My jQuery code:

```
var cardForm = $('#card-form');
cardForm.hide();

$("#display-card-form").click(function (e) {
   cardForm.show();
   e.preventDefault();
 });
```

Comment: Do you have the modal set to a specific height?

Comment: I did not set any height

Comment: Ok...one more question.  What version of bootstrap are you currently on?

Comment: **v3.3.2** is the version of the Bootstrap I use. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, upgrade from v3.3.2 to **v3.3.4**. This issue will be resolved.

I attempted an example first in 3.3.4, as that is what I am on.  Once you specified you were on 3.3.2, I downgraded and saw your issue.  This was a bug they fixed in the latest release ([#15881](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/15881)).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @cfnerd! My mistake I did not read their bug fixes.

Comment: @VladMatvei No problem...I often skim over those changelog notes, too!